# Should a converter directly access a repository?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I couldn't find an answer anywhere to this particular problem, which made me second guess my architecture. Basically I have two entities, BaseCategoryEntity and ItemEntity.

```
@Entity
public class ItemEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long itemId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "BCID", nullable = false)
private BaseCategoryEntity baseCategory;

@Column(name = "NAME", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String name;

....
```

ItemEntity has it's corresponding DTO, `Item`. `ItemController` receives an `Item`, passes it to the `ItemService`, which using a converter saves it to the repository.

```
@Service
public class ItemService {

  @Autowired
  ItemRepository repository; //this is a CrudRepository

  @Autowired
  ItemConverter converter;

  public void add(Item item){
      repository.save(converter.convertFrom(item));
  }

}
```

And the converter looks like this

```
@Component
public class ItemConverter{

  @Autowired
  BaseCategoryConverter bcConverter;

  public ItemEntity convertFrom(Item model) {
    ItemEntity entity = new ItemEntity();
    entity.setName(model.getName());         
entity.setBaseCategory(bcConverter.convertFrom(model.getBaseCategoryName()));
    return entity;
  }
}
```

By running this code I get *org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value* error, because the id for BaseCategoryEntity isn't set. 
The easiest way to resolve this issue seems to be autowiring `ItemRepository` to `ItemConverter` and `BaseCategoryRepository` to `BaseCategoryConverter`, so I would be able to change `convertFrom` to first check if the entity already exists and use that one, or create and save it if it doesn't.
However it seems out of place for a converter to do such logic.

Comment: Based what you want to do, you can simply put `name` as foreign key and not `id` then it should work. I mean `BCID` this should be `BCNAME`  or something like that.

Comment: In this particular case, yes, but the question rather aims for the concept, since I have multiple entities like these 2, but with a bunch of other fields. I chose these to represent the problem, because they are the simplest

Comment: If you want to keep what is now, then you answered your question.

Comment: Not really. I'm fairly new to Spring Boot thus I don't know all the best practices there are. I would like to keep `ItemService` the only one accessing the repository, but with this setup the converters also need to access it.

Comment: The best practice is what I commented you `name` as `foreign key` and you forget to access to `repository or service` .